# Passando o "video-Index" de uma playlist em um iFrame do YouTube

Tags: youtube-api, embed

Estou criando um site onde quero exibir os dois últimos vídeos postados em um determinado canal, mas não consigo passar os parâmetros de `index` do vídeo pelo `src` do `iframe` como mostrado abaixo:

```html
<iframe 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLYFQKMIdrXSbuNYzQmrc8ocTdT6u4EZGe&index=0"
  frameborder="0" 
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
  allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLYFQKMIdrXSbuNYzQmrc8ocTdT6u4EZGe&index=1" 
  frameborder="0" 
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com uma possível solução para meu problema?

Comment: Ola @Lucas bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour], -- fiz uma edição na descrição de sua pergunta, se minha edição não representa sua duvida você pode reverte ela [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/394618/revisions) -- =D

Answer (score 1):

Brother, se vc colocar assim vai ver que funciona.. o problema no seu caso é que o video com index = 1, é um video privado ou está quebrado e não pode ser adicionado ao embed!

```html
<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLYFQKMIdrXSbuNYzQmrc8ocTdT6u4EZGe&index=0"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLYFQKMIdrXSbuNYzQmrc8ocTdT6u4EZGe&index=3"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz desse jeito e não tinha dado certo, mas já consegui...
Vou postar a solução aqui pra caso alguém mais procure a respeito:

```
//Último Vídeo postado no canal
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=[UPLOAD_PLAYLIST_ID]&index=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

//Penúltimo Vídeo postado no canal
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=[UPLOAD_PLAYLIST_ID]&index=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```